# How do I insert the primary key to another table as foreign key?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables 
`tbl_cars` and `tbl_user` 
Where `tbl_user` has `userID` as `Primary key` 
I declared it as a Foreign key on my `tbl_cars` 
Whenever a user logs in it can't post an item to the `tbl_cars` I get this error

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (u850332371_car.tbl_cars, CONSTRAINT tbl_cars_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY
>   (userID) REFERENCES tbl_user (userID))

This is my code for inserting.

### Insert.php

```
<?PHP
$conn = new mysqli('******', '******', '******', '******');

 if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);// at top of page

if(isset($_POST['txtCarModel']) && isset($_POST['txtCarType']) && 
isset($_POST['txtCapacity']) && isset($_POST['image']) &&
isset($_POST['txtFuelType']) && isset($_POST['txtPlateNumber'])){

$now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
$id = $now->format('YmdHis');

$upload_folder = "upload";
$path = "$upload_folder/$id.jpeg";
$image = $_POST['image'];
$fullpath = "http://carkila.esy.es/$upload_folder/$id.jpeg";

$Car_Model = $_POST['txtCarModel'];
$Car_Type = $_POST['txtCarType'];
$Capacity = $_POST['txtCapacity'];
$Fuel_Type = $_POST['txtFuelType'];
$PlateNumber = $_POST['txtPlateNumber'];
$Image = $_POST['image'];


$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_cars (Car_Model, Car_Type, Capacity, fuelType, carPlatenuNumber, Image) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?,?,?)");
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_cars(Car_Model, Car_Type, Capacity,fuelType, carPlatenuNumber, Image) 
VALUES ('$Car_Model', '$Car_Type', $Capacity, '$Fuel_Type', '$PlateNumber', '$fullpath')"; 

$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $Car_Model, $Car_Type, $Capacity,$Fuel_Type,$PlateNumber, $fullpath);
$result = $stmt->execute();

if($result === false ) {
  die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}else{
echo "New records created successfully";
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

    }


?>
```

### UPDATE

This is my login with sessions. I want the userID to be in the insertion of data to the database.

### login.php

```
<?php 
require 'database-config.php';

session_start();

$username = "";
$password = "";

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
}
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
$password = $_POST['password'];

}


$q = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username=:username AND password=:password';

$query = $dbh->prepare($q);

$query->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));


if($query->rowCount() == 0){
header('Location: index.php?err=1');
}else{

$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

session_regenerate_id();
 $_SESSION['sess_user_id'] = $row['userID'];
 $_SESSION['sess_username'] = $row['username'];
 $_SESSION['sess_userrole'] = $row['roles'];

 echo $_SESSION['sess_userrole'];
session_write_close();

if( $_SESSION['sess_userrole'] == "renter"){
echo "owner";

}else if ($_SESSION['sess_userrole'] == "owner"){
echo"renter";

}


}


?>
```

Thank you guys. :)

Comment: Mysql or SQL-Server?

Comment: @Jens - Mysql sorry. Hahaha! Accidentally clicked all the suggested tags. XD

Comment: You have to add the user id to your insert statement

Comment: @Jens - How can it be sir. Doesn't it will be posted as the same as the primary key that is logged in? O.o

Answer (score 0):

> whenever a user logs in it can't post an item...

Since you know which user is trying to add a record to `tbl_cars`, include `userID` in your insert.

```
$userID = ... //<- put the user id in this variable
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_cars ('.
       'userID,Car_Model,Car_Type,Capacity,fuelType,carPlatenuNumber,Image'.
       ') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $userID $Car_Model, $Car_Type, $Capacity,
                             $Fuel_Type,$PlateNumber, $fullpath);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

I believe your problem is that `userID` is a required field, but the DB cannot insert a default value for you when you don't provide one because the value must be bound to a primary key in `tbl_user`

Comment: Indeed.  UserID is probably held in a session variable, at a guess.

Comment: Does that automatically inserts the primary key of the `tbl_user`?

Comment: @Jeyjey No. If you try to insert a record that doesn't match a key from `tbl_user` it won't work.  The foreign key constraint means that you want every record in `tbl_cars` to be linked to a record in `tbl_user`, so there is no automatic insertion.  If you want to be able to enter `userID`s in `tbl_cars` that don't already exist in `tbl_user`, then you should remove the foreign key constraint.

Comment: Uhm, sir I have edited the codes. does my login with session helps with my problem I have sessions with my userID. Thanks sir.

Comment: @eggyal - Sir, how can I do it with sessions. My login have sessions sir. :)

Comment: Just bind `$_SESSION['sess_user_id']` to the parameter for `tbl_cars.UserID`?

Comment: @eggyal - How sir? Beginner programmer here. LOL HAHAHAHA!

Comment: If you don't know that, then clearly you don't understand the code you already have—I suggest you go back to basics, take it one step at a time, and really make an effort to learn what it is that your code is doing.

Comment: @Jeyjey Was it your own code that you shared?  Because based on the code, I thought my answer was straightforward.  Anyway I've updated my answer to be more explicit.